# "Often" and "oftentimes"

Tags: word-choice, differences, adverbs

Is there any difference between the two terms 'often' and 'oftentimes'? They seem to be used interchangeably but is one more appropriate in certain situations than others? Is 'oftentimes' an older term that is commonly replaced by 'often' nowadays?

Consider this sentence:

> - Physiological tolerances can be measured indirectly by quantifying species’ occurrences along environmental axes (citation), which is *often* the only way such information can be recorded for large numbers of species.
> - Physiological tolerances can be measured indirectly by quantifying species’ occurrences along environmental axes (citation), which is *oftentimes* the only way such information can be recorded for large numbers of species.

Comment: No one uses oftentimes. It's recognizable, but sounds old-fashioned.

Comment: What Mitch said. You definitely wouldn't use it in a paragraph starting with such precise technical terminology as the example here. It's effectively archaic, but sufficiently well-known that oftentimes people just throw it in somewhat light-heartedly.

Comment: Grammar.com says "*Often* is a shortened version of the bigger word *oftentimes*".  This is quite funny, considering that "often" is the original word, and "oftentimes" came about when people pointlessly stuck the word "times" on the end of it back in the 14th century.  Btw, regarding "no one uses oftentimes": M.-Webster says, "Despite its archaic, literary ring, oftentimes is quite alive today. In fact, it seems to be more popular even now than it was thirty years or so ago, appearing frequently both in written expressions and speech" ( https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oftentimes )

Answer (score 14):

*Often* and *oftentimes* may be used with little or no distinction to mean again and again in more or less close succession, but *oftentimes* is occasionally preferred for intonational reasons ("*He had a sense of humor which was sometimes loud, oftentimes lewd, but never deliberately unkind [...].*")<sup>(1)</sup>

In the following NGRAM *often* is compared to *oftentimes*<sup>(2)</sup>.

[image]

It would seem that the use of *oftentimes* is very rare in written English language.

<sup>(1)</sup> *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms*
<sup>(2)</sup> *NGRAM is for written language only, of course.*

Comment: That NGRAM plot is a nice way to visualize the difference in term usage! +1

Comment: If you give an image of the ngram, you'll also want to give a link to ngram with the parameters you used, both for convenience of those who want to look at the details, but also so we know what parameters you used. I tried to repeat yours and though the general trend was the same, the graphs do not match exactly so I wonder what could be different between the two.

Comment: I think it's putting it a bit strongly to say that *oftentimes* is "very rare" in written usage (though it is pretty uncommon in *spoken* usage). It's just that you're graphing it against *often*, which is a "**very common**" word. As it happens, **oftentimes** I use the word myself, albeit almost invariably in a somewhat tongue in cheek way. But quite **often** it turns out these two words aren't totally interchangeable (as in this sentence! :)

Comment: @Mitch - Please, see here: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0624hd885

Comment: @Carlo_R., I think Mitch means a link like so: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=often%2Coftentimes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: @zleptan, yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: I see from your screenshot (a direct link is better) that you set the parameters to look at the American English corpus. As useful as that is, it is probably better to start with the entire English corpus, and then if the issue is considered relevant, show -both- British and American corpuses together for comparison. Showing just the American version is somewhat ... insular.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: yes, that is a difficulty with ngrams, figuring if the 'rarity' is only relative or absolute. Just because a term 'flatlines' in a comparison, doesn't mean it is non-existent; in some sense it is a wonder that the word comparisons we've been doing here ever show anything other than one item dominating and the other flatlining.

Comment: @Mitch Did you really just say *corpuses*?  Everyone in the NLP field says *corpora*.  Honest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You get a slightly different picture if you look at 1600–1800. Also, a simple *oft* used to be used a bit, and would find its way into compounds like *oft-times*, *ofttimes*, and *oftimes*.  I don’t know how to make Google Ngrams work right with hypenated words; I suspect it doesn’t.

Comment: @tchrist: yes, I did just say that. I used to say 'lemmmata' and 'formulae' (pronounced correctly) and 'vertices' and 'cherubim'. My fellow geeks made fun of me. Now I only say 'formulas'. [I've come to enjoy 'America's got talent', too](http://www.orange-papers.org/orange-thinker.html).

Comment: @Mitch,tchrist: If you include a hyphen in NGram search text, nothing ever matches, but in Google Books it's processed as if you'd typed a space. Both systems match hyphens (and many other punctuation marks) in the actual indexed text as if they were spaces. The way they handle apostrophes is too weird for me to figure out - but they definitely do *something* on that front (I'm with Mitch on corpuses, btw! :)

Answer (score 4):

I can't find a difference in any of my online dictionaries. My best guess:

- *Often* is an adverb meaning *frequently*.
- *Oftentimes* is an adverb phrase-turned-word, and is similar to the adverb phrase *many times*. (The Oxford Dictionaries Online note that *oftentimes* is archaic or North American.)

In your example, then, either word is fine—you could substitute *frequently* or *many times* and see that the grammaticality of the sentence is preserved.

Usually (always?), *often* can replace *oftentimes*; however, the reverse is not true—for instance, you wouldn't say, "I don't do that oftentimes."

Comment: See also http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2011/09/oftentimes.html

Answer (score 4):

They mean the same thing.  However, "oftentimes" is colloquial and informal, and should not be used in scholarly or academic work.

Answer (score 3):

I have only ever heard American English speakers use "oftentimes", never British. It's not the case that "oftentimes" is exclusive to American English but it certainly appears to be more common.

Comment: Me too.  I think it *is* more or less exclusive to American English, at least in modern use (I know it was used in the 1611 Bible).